# Replacing Gutenberg Featured Image control?

Tags: post-thumbnails, block-editor

I can replace the Featured Image control in current WP version by PHP:

```
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'my_admin_post_thumbnail_html', 10, 2 );
```

How do I do the same thing with Gutenberg?

Comment: This might be better raised on the GB issue tracker at GitHub, but I will say that since the new picker is entirely done in React, the likelihood of an equivalent filter working the same way is very low

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for the heads-up, has posted there

Comment: Ah you deleted it  :( what if you find the answer, and come back and post it, or somebody else opens the same question, I'd undelete it if I were you :) It does no harm sitting here, and lots of deleted answers might fool the system into thinking you're a bad actor

Comment: @TomJNowell, okey, some people are very critic at what question should be posted where and I didn't want to receive down votes.

Comment: Little late, but maybe this is relevant: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/editor/src/components/post-featured-image#postfeaturedimage However, I haven't yet figured out how to actually insert any components in place of "The replacement contents or components."

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of adding a new component to the Featured Image area. This was taken from the official docs and updated to use JSX. I am using the `@wordpress/scripts` package to build this out.

```
// Import from the hooks package
import { addFilter } from '@wordpress/hooks';

// Some custom component to add.
const CustomComponent = ({ id }) => {
    return id ? (
        <h4>You selected an image, yay!</h4>
    ) : (
        <div>You have not selected anything</div>
    );
};

// Function to be called by the hook that returns a function containing the new UI
function replacePostFeaturedImage(OriginalComponent) {
    return (props) => {
        const { featuredImageId } = props;
        return (
            <div>
                <CustomComponent id={featuredImageId} />
                <OriginalComponent {...props} />
            </div>
        );
    };
}

// Register the hook.
addFilter(
    'editor.PostFeaturedImage',
    'my-plugin/replace-post-featured-image',
    replacePostFeaturedImage
);
```

To replace the entire component, just remove `<OriginalComponent />` from the `replacePostFeaturedImage` function.

Hope it helps and happy to add any further context as needed!